# API Help How to get last tab in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, discord.js

How to get the last tab of a json code?
ex:

```
{
  "claimed_levels": {
      "level_1",
      "level_2"
    }
}
```

What i am trying to get is when someone do !levels

it shows
Your level is "2"

i tried using `.length`

But it responded as undefined.

Comment: As @prateek3636 pointed out, your JSON object is not valid.  `.length` is only available on a JSON array/collection. You are using neither here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a valid json object.

```
{
  "claimed_levels": {
     "level_1",
     "level_2"
  }
}
```

you are using "claimed_levels" as key for object and it's value is an object, which is:

```
{
  "level_1",
  "level_2"
}
```

But it's not a right object, you should use array like:

```
[
  "level_1",
  "level_2"
]
```

Or key value pair object like:

```
{
  "level_1":"1",
  "level_2":"2"
}
```

Comment: Yes it is

`{
"level_1": true,
"level_2": true
}`
But is there's a way to do that?

Comment: No, because `.length` is a property on an array/collection. The closest thing you could do in that case would be something like `Object.keys({"level_1": true, "level_2": true}).length` which would tell you the number of keys in the JSON object, in this case 2.

Comment: You have to use Object.keys(`object`).length

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
let input = {
    "claimed_levels": {
        "level_1": true,
        "level_2": true
    }
};
let cl = input.claimed_levels;
console.log(Object.keys(cl)[Object.keys(cl).length-1]);
```

You need to be careful about what you mean by "last". Older JavaScript specs said that you can never count on the ordering of object keys. While that has changed, it still may depend on implementation. Specifically, you might need to test if "level_10" would sort before "level_2" (alphabetically).

Answer (score -1):

.length send the array length. almost all programming languages start index from 0. then [array.length-1] may work.

Comment: Hi, Mahdi! I'd like to inform you that you need to consider the fact that array.length can be 0. In this case, array.length - 1 will be -1 and this will cause an error.

Comment: This is also not an array

Comment: I assume we convert the string to array